# Como "funciona" a Propriedade de Dependência(DependencyProperty)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estou tentando entender o recurso de propriedades de dependência. Já li alguns tutoriais no msdn mas o recurso ainda está obscuro para mim.

Exemplo:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3 {

   /// <summary> 
      /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml 
   /// </summary> 

   public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {

      public UserControl1() {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty
         SetTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SetText", typeof(string), 
         typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSetTextChanged)));

      public string SetText {
         get {return(string) GetValue(SetTextProperty); }
         set {SetValue(SetTextProperty, value);}
      }

      private static void OnSetTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
         UserControl1 UserControl1Control = d as UserControl1;
         UserControl1Control.OnSetTextChanged(e);
      }

      private void OnSetTextChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
         tbTest.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
      }
   }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class = "WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
   xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:views = "clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" 
   Title = "MainWindow" Height = "350" Width = "604">

   <Grid>
      <views:UserControl1 SetText = "Hellow World" />
   </Grid>

</Window>
```

Não estou entendendo a "mecânica" do funcionamento dos métodos da classe `UserControl1`. Ou seja, em que momento eles estão sendo chamados, e por quem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que uma propriedade de um *UserControl([DependencyObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.110).aspx))* possa ser usada no XAML e assim poder ser acedida/calculada por outros meios, que não os tradicionais "get" e "set", tais como *themes*, *binding*, animações, *templates*, etc, ela tem de ser declarada como [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) e registada no *"WPF property system*".

Isso é feito recorrendo ao método estático `Register()` da classe *DependencyProperty*.

Uma *Dependency Property* é composta por duas "partes":

- **Identificador da propriedade** - Uma instância de *DependencyProperty* obtida pelo retorno do método `DependencyProperty.Register()` e guardada como um membro estático do *DependencyObject*. Esse identificador é usado como parâmetro para muitas das APIs que interagem com o *"WPF property system*".
  A convenção obriga a que o seu nome seja o da propriedade acrescido de `Property`

  ```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SetTextProperty = 
      DependencyProperty.Register("SetText", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1),
               new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSetTextChanged)));
  ```
- **CLR "wrapper"** - A real implementação da propriedade. Essa implementação recorre ao identificador e aos métodos `GetValue()` e `SetValue()` do *DependencyObject* para implementar o "get" e "set" da propriedade.

  ```
  public string SetText 
  {
       get {return(string) GetValue(SetTextProperty); }
       set {SetValue(SetTextProperty, value);}
  }
  ```

O método `DependencyProperty.Register()` tem 3 *overloads*:

- [public static DependencyProperty Register(String name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597500(v=vs.110).aspx) - Regista uma *dependency property* com o nome indicado, o seu tipo e tipo do seu proprietário. Isto é o mínimo necessário para registar a propriedade.
- [public static DependencyProperty Register(string name,Type propertyType,Type ownerType,PropertyMetadata typeMetadata)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502(v=vs.110).aspx) - Regista uma *dependency property* com o nome indicado, o seu tipo, tipo do seu proprietário e metadados.
- [public static DependencyProperty Register(string name,Type propertyType,Type ownerType,PropertyMetadata typeMetadata, ValidateValueCallback validateValueCallback)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597501(v=vs.110).aspx) - Regista uma *dependency property* com o nome indicado, o seu tipo, tipo do seu proprietário, metadados e um *callback* para validação do valor.

Ao fazer o registo da propriedade, além de indicar o nome, tipo e tipo do seu proprietário é possível indicar vários *callbacks*,

Esses *callbacks* são:

- [PropertyChangedCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) - Via [PropertyMetadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata(v=vs.110).aspx), é chamado quando o valor da propriedade é alterado.
- [CoerceValueCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.coercevaluecallback(v=vs.110).aspx) - Via PropertyMetadata, é chamado quando o valor estar a ser avaliado.
- [ValidateValueCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.validatevaluecallback(v=vs.110).aspx) - É chamado após o valor da propriedade ser atribuido. Deve retornar `true` ou `false` de acordo com a validação.

Assim, respondendo à sua pergunta, esses métodos estão a ser chamados pelo *"WPF property system*" enquanto interage com a propriedade.

Mais informação em [Dependency Properties Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: A propriedade precisa necessariamente ser estática? Não entendi o papel do método estático sobre carregado `OnSetTextChanged` vejo que ele apenas cria um objeto e chama o método que fará a alteração.

Comment: Sim a propriedade necessita de ser estática. Em relação ao método `OnSetTextChanged()`, foi algo que eu também reparei, ele não necessita de ser sobrecarregado. Apenas é necessário declará-lo com a assinatura `void OnSetTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)`, que é aquela que corresponde ao `delegate` *PropertyChangedCallback*, e lá colocar o código a executar quando a propriedade for alterada, neste caso, `tbTest.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();`.